# Set redirect URL for Spotify API

Tags: python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

I know there have been multiple questions regarding this issue... however, I'm not sure how to handle my case.

I am using spotipy to access the Spotify API. In my python notebook, I entered:

```
util.prompt_for_user_token('<user_id>',client_id='<client_id>',client_secret='<client_secret>',redirect_uri='localhost:3000/callback/')
```

On the spotify developer website, I have listed localhost:3000/callback/ as my redirect URL.

When I run the prompt, I am redirected to the spotify page where I would click 'okay' to authorize the account. However, each time I click the 'okay' button, nothing happens. Tried using a separate browser, tried restarting my computer... I'm not sure what to do.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After being redirected, the library should prompt you to copy the URL you're redirected to and paste it back in your python notebook. It then grabs the access token from the URL and uses it to authenticate.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. However, I keep getting an error in my python notebook stating "Bad Request".

Comment: Is there any extra info on the error? An error code or some extra text like "Invalid redirect uri"?

Comment: No there isn't. The only other information I get is that the function fails when at the task: token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code).